# Create an array of UIColor in swift

Tags: ios, swift2, nsmutablearray, uicolor

Why is this giving me an error?

```
 var colorArray = [UIColor.self]

colorArray.append(UIColor.redColor()) //error here
colorArray.removeLast()
```

how do I define a mutable array to store `UIColor`?

Comment: var colorArray = [UIColor]()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@George Asda:

The error coming up is "Cannot convert value type 'UIColor' to expected argument type 'UIColor.Type'"

The error disappears when an empty array of type UIColor is set up e.g. below I have replicated it...

```
var uiColorArray = [UIColor]()   // Empty Array of type UIColor
```

Subsequently, when I append and removeLast like in your example and print at each stage, all appears fine without any error... e.g. inside a Func...

```
self.uiColorArray.append(UIColor.blueColor) // in Swift 3, its UIColor.blue
    print(uiColorArray)

    self.uiColorArray.removeLast()
    print(uiColorArray)
```

Error is gone.

Answer (score 4):

**Updated for Swift 3**

```
let colorArray = [UIColor.red, UIColor.green, UIColor.blue]
```